# IBAction on Button Press

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton

A discussion.  Which is more preferred:

A single IBAction with sender and a bunch of if statements
ex: `if (sender == self.whichbuttonpressed)`

or

A single IBAction with sender and a switch statement
ex: `switch (send.tag)`  // short handed for easier reading

or

an IBAction for each button.

for the discussion lets say we have 6 or less buttons in the XIB file.

Thanks

PS make believe your grandma is reading your responses so no sarcasm please, be real.

Comment: Being a witty pompous smart-ass, I hereby tell you: "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers". Is your grandmother a professional programmer?

Comment: Preferred by who? The different constructs make sense in different situations, use the one which matches your use case the best.

Comment: I am very happy that you identified yourself.  Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation depends on your app, but consider this..

Say you were implementing a number pad, with 10 buttons (0 through 9). The only difference when pressing each button is the number is represents. So, if you set each button's tag to the numeric value the button is supposed to represent, handling 10 buttons with a single IBAction method becomes trivial:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
        int value = b.tag;

        // Do something with value...
    }
```

I have used this approach for a variety of situations where a single view contains many buttons that all essentially do the same thing but can be distinguished behind the scenes by assigning a unique tag to each one.

If you have a view with many buttons but they are unrelated to one another, then each button should probably have it's own IBAction method. Doing so in this case keeps the unique implementation for each button's action much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using **tags**, so

> A single IBAction with sender and a switch statement ex: switch (send.tag) // short handed for easier reading

Last approach is reasonable if actions for different buttons are significantly different

Answer (score 1):

Definitely an IBAction for each button.  Clean.  Simple.  Enables you to add or remove an action or a button without editing and possibly introducing errors into the code for the other actions.

Comment: I second that. it's much more modular.

Comment: I tend to agree with you, but it's a very broad question, depending heavily on the precise UI and application. I think it cannot be answered in its current form and does not bring much to SO...

Comment: @Kheldar - Yeah. It's not in good form for StackOverflow, given that he says he's looking for a discussion, but ...

Comment: Its been years, but i feel the need to add that this isn't always true. The case scenario MarkGranoff mentions was part of the 2011 and 2012 CS193 Stanford course as the correct way to handle many calculator digits in that course's assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I actually the second and third ones you list. Tags are definitely easier to work with than a bunch of if statements. If I have a bunch of buttons on one view that are totally unrelated, I generally use separate IBActions. If they relate to each other then I use 1 IBAction so I don't have to repeat myself.

Example:

1. Login and Signup buttons: different IBActions. One needs to push a VC, the other needs to make a webservice call for authentication.
2. Breadcrumbs. In an app I'm working on right now we have a bar of breadcrumbs that are steps a user has to complete in order. I use 1 IBAction to handle those because 1. their states change in a consistent way and 2. they all essentially perform the same action (swapping in their corresponding view in the form).